# SSRS appears to be ignoring Permissions set using Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions, ssrs

I have setup SSRS on SQL Server 2008 in native mode.

As an administrator I can login to report manager, upload reports and run them, and also use the Web Service URL to generate reports.

I have also created a local user on the machine, I went into Report Manager as Admin, and at the top level set permissions that should assign the local user to all roles.

When I login to the machine as that user, and then navigate to Report Manager I just get the heading for the page, but do not see any of the folders that are configured.

I've checked and the folders are set to inherit parent permissions and they are showing the newly created local user in there too.

It seems odd that I have set the permissions, yet SSRS is still not showing what I should be able to see. Is there another step I need to take other than configuring the permissions in Report Manager?

When logged in as the newly created local user:

```
Report Manager - Shows the heading for the page, but no folders/items

Web Service URL (http://machine/ReportServer) - rsAccessDeniedError
```

Comment: On the Home (root) folder, if you go to Properties - Security, do you see the local user account there?  Is this where you set up the local user?

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried running IE as an admin? There are issues connecting locally with IE when it is not.

Comment: I did add the permission at the root folder, and I see the user listed here under Properties - Security.

Also I have ran IE as admin, had to do this to be able to get the option for setting permissions. Once set it seems very hit and miss whether they take effect.

I tried creating another user, granted them permissions at the root folder, then when I logged in as that user and tried to access Report Manager I don't see any folders/items at all.

Comment: Do you have active directory where you're doing this?  Also, are you naming the users as servername/username in SSRS?

Comment: One more thing, could you provide a screen shot of the permissions you're setting?

Comment: I'll get a screenshot today, not been in the office so have been late to respond - There is no AD on that box, the username is in the format of "MachineName\Username" in the Report Manager settings. All set on the root folder.


Does SSRS require that the server be reset when permissions are added/removed? I didn't think so myself.. In my experiences previously this hasn't been the case

Answer (score 4):

To give a user rights to work with SSRS they need to have permissions at the root folder (which is what it sounds like you have done), but you also have to go into the "site settings" link into  the "security" tab and add the user as (at minimum) a system user. 
It is easy to do one, but not the other. Both are required to allow full access to the system.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mr. Bennett's comment, I have run into some problems on Windows machines using UAC where the browser needs to run 'as Administrator'.  Sometimes there are IE Enhanced Security settings that need to be adjusted (Administrator vs. User).