# how to list the SSRS permissions in each folder in the reporting services server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssrs, powershell, ssrs-2016

I have the following powershell script that [downloads](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/157561/22336) all the [RDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/report-definition-language-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) from a reporting services [server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185325/22336).

I am not the author to whom I am very thankful. It has been very useful for downloading the RDLs.

```
#note this is tested on PowerShell v2 and SSRS 2008 R2
#marcelo miorelli
#23-oct-2018
#How to Download All Your SSRS Report Definitions (RDL files) Using PowerShell
#Written by belle

#Here’s a short PowerShell script that :
#1. Connects to your report server
#2. Creates the same folder structure you have in your Report Server
#3. Download all the SSRS Report Definition (RDL) files into their respective folders

#In addition to backing up your Source Project, your ReportServer database, or good old RSScripter 
#(see http://sqlserver-indo.org/blogs/mca/archive/2009/03/08/extract-and-transfer-rdl-files-from-ssrs.aspx) 
#this is just another way you can “backup” or archive your reports.


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.XmlDocument");
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO");

$ReportServerUri = "http://qg-v-sqlrs-pr/Reportserver/Reportservice2005.asmx"      #"http://yourreportserver/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx";
$Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2005 -UseDefaultCredential ;

#check out all members of $Proxy
#$Proxy | Get-Member
#http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225878(v=SQL.80).aspx

#second parameter means recursive
$items = $Proxy.ListChildren("/", $true) | 
         select Type, Path, ID, Name | 
         Where-Object {$_.type -eq "Report"};

#create a new folder where we will save the files
#PowerShell datetime format codes http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

#create a timestamped folder, format similar to 2011-Mar-28-0850PM
$folderName = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MMM-dd-hhmmtt";
$fullFolderName = "D:\SSRS_Export\" + $folderName;
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($fullFolderName) | out-null

foreach($item in $items)
{
    #need to figure out if it has a folder name
    $subfolderName = split-path $item.Path;
    $reportName = split-path $item.Path -Leaf;
    $fullSubfolderName = $fullFolderName + $subfolderName;
    if(-not(Test-Path $fullSubfolderName))
    {
        #note this will create the full folder hierarchy
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($fullSubfolderName) | out-null
    }

    $rdlFile = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
    [byte[]] $reportDefinition = $null;
    $reportDefinition = $Proxy.GetReportDefinition($item.Path);

    #note here we're forcing the actual definition to be 
    #stored as a byte array
    #if you take out the @() from the MemoryStream constructor, you'll 
    #get an error
    [System.IO.MemoryStream] $memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(@(,$reportDefinition));
    $rdlFile.Load($memStream);

    $fullReportFileName = $fullSubfolderName + "\" + $item.Name +  ".rdl";
    #Write-Host $fullReportFileName;
    $rdlFile.Save( $fullReportFileName);

}
```

The problem that I am having on this particular server is that [apparently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34053/22336) I don't have enough [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54145/22336) to download reports.

I would like to identify where exactly I am lacking permissions.
How can I achieve that?

Alternatively, how could I list all the permissions in each folder in SSRS?

Here is the error message I get:

[image]

here is the text of the error message:

```
Exception calling "GetReportDefinition" with "1" argument(s): "The permissions granted to user 'mycompany\MMiorelli' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'mycompany\MMiorelli' are insufficient for performing this 
operation."
At line:62 char:5
+     $reportDefinition = $Proxy.GetReportDefinition($item.Path);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Buffer cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer"
At line:68 char:43
+ ... memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream(@(,$reportDefinition)); ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Root element is missing."
At line:69 char:5
+     $rdlFile.Load($memStream);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid XML document. The document does not have a root element."
At line:73 char:5
+     $rdlFile.Save( $fullReportFileName);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: Yes I can query the `ReportServer` and if you have more info as how to find all the permissions on the folders we would love to hear from you, even if it is not a complete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to this question, but as an alternative and certainly very useful,

I have followed the advise and [link](https://github.com/petervandivier/hello-world/blob/master/sql/all-rdls.sql) provided by [Peter Vandivier](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68127/peter-vandivier) in the comments above and doing some changes in the original script, like [how to convert to VARBINARY(MAX)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63745/22336) and even considered [master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46920/22336) but it was too slow.

Here is the modified script, it gives all of the RDL files - it is an expensive query but it seems to work.

In my environment it took about a minute to return 348 reports. My powershell script returned 347 reports and complained about permissions, no complains about permissions here.

```
use ReportServer
go

with VarBinMax as ( 
    select 
         ItemID
        ,VarBinMax    = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),[Content],1)
        ,HasBom       = CONVERT(BIT,IIF(
                        LEFT(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),[Content],1),3)=0xEFBBBF,1,0))
        ,LenVarBinMax = LEN(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),[Content],1))
        ,[Type]
    from [Catalog]
    where [Type] = 2
) -- select top(10) * from VarBinMax
, ContentNoBom as (
    select 
         ItemID
        ,ContentNoBom = CONVERT(VARBINARY(max),
                        IIF(HasBom=1,SUBSTRING(VarBinMax,4,LenVarBinMax),VarBinMax))
    from VarBinMax
)  
--select top(10) * from ContentNoBom
select 
     ItemID
    ,RdlXml  = CONVERT(XML,ContentNoBom)
    ,RdlText = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(XML,ContentNoBom))
into #RDL
from ContentNoBom cnb

select * 
from #RDL
```